# Who is the deity of Devi Puran (A.k.a Mahabhagwat)?can you explain more?

Tags: devi, shakti, shaktism, devi-bhagavata-purana

According to Devi Puran Mahabhagwat, when vyas ji wanted to know the param tatva, he started to meditate on Shakti at the top of himalaya. After hard penance devi appeared as Akashvaani and said vyas will know the param tatva at brahmalok by shrutis and vedas. After that vyas ji went for brahmaloka and asked vedas for Avinashi Param tatva. Then 4 vedas replied him as Devi MahaDurga as para brahma. And started devi stotra, where they said that- aah i am not giving that stotra here.I think you know those lines. So, my doubt is they said,  that para brahma which is free from male and female forms, first got his/her wish of creation because of your power. And that parashakti devided herself in two form-Param Purush and parashakti was also with your power. Thats why parabrahma is also shakti's form.

Now my verily doubt is what those 4 vedas were trying to explain at that time? Devi Durga as Parabrahma or Maya? Because as per the stotra they were indicating devi durga as maya, as maya is the one who help parabrahma to take sagun form. And with help of maya parabrahma appears in bija form. I think Vedas were talking about Yogmaya as Mahadurga.

Please explain it. It's confusing